# how to use relative path in .sh in order to make my tar files include only the folder tar is created from instead of its fullpath

Tags: linux, bash, relative-path

In a mono exe I am creating .sh scripts file containing codes as below

tarcreator.sh:

```
tar -cvf /data/folder1/folder2/.../xyz.tar /data/...../tarHomeFolder/myTarFolder > /data/logs/tarLogs.txt
```

....
and the codes continue.

this .sh file is located in /data/...../tarHomeFolder and in my .exe I call it using "bash 'full path of .sh file'"

When I run this code in this way, it creates the tar but when I open the tar I see folders from the root directory.. (data/..../tarHomeFolder/myTarFolder/.....) instead of this I want my tar contain only directory structure of its folder (myTarFolder).

Then I changed the code to :

```
tar -cvf /data/folder1/folder2/.../xyz.tar myTarFolder > /data/logs/tarLogs.txt
```

knowing that .sh file is in tarHomeFolder but then my script tells no such file or directory for myTarFolder ..

when I use tar command right in command prompt, using the command

```
tar -cvf /data/folder1/folder2/.../xyz.tar myTarFolder > /data/logs/tarLogs.txt
```

it creates the tar directory structure as I want, so, how can I make it do the same in my bash file created and executed by mono .exe ?

Comment: i just noticed why i had no such file or directory error, it is because the mono .exe file interprets the relative paths relative to its own path. the .exe is in /data/....../tarApps and the tarHomeFolder could be reached from tarApps using cd ../tarHomeFolder   when i changed this it created the tar file, but this time the tar's root directory was named "..\tarHomeFolder\myTarFolder......" so, does this change any suggestions you provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is change your directory before running `tar`. Something like this:

```
# If your full path to the directory is in DIR = "/data/...../tarHomeFolder/myTarFolder"
cd $(dirname $DIR)
tar -cvf /data/folder1/folder2/.../xyz.tar $(basename $DIR) > /data/logs/tarLogs.txt
```

This will leave you with relative paths, starting with `myTarFolder`, in your tar file.

Useful references:

- [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html)
- [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html)

Comment: thank you, i just tested your suggestion, and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

tar -cvf /data/folder1/folder2/.../xyz.tar -C /data/...../tarHomeFolder/ myTarFolder > /data/logs/tarLogs.txt

Comment: It's not as visible as I intended, there's a -C option with the path to tarHomeFolder, and the final "bare" argument is the myTarFolder, relative to that.